# Test failing with method not beeing called in test

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I am attempting to test a Passport Strategy as defined below. I am using Magic SDK for authentication.

magic.strategy.ts

```js
import { Magic } from '@magic-sdk/admin'
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common'
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { DoneFunc, Strategy } from 'passport-magic'
import { UserFromDid } from '../../types/magic.types'
import { UsersService } from '../../users/users.service'

@Injectable()
export class MagicStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'magic') {
    private readonly logger = new Logger(MagicStrategy.name)

    constructor(
        private readonly config: ConfigService, 
        private readonly userService: UsersService
    ) {
        const magic = new Magic(config.get('MAGIC_SECRET_KEY'))

        super({
            magicInstance: magic,
        },
        async function (user: UserFromDid, done: DoneFunc) {
            const userMetadata = await magic.users.getMetadataByIssuer(user.issuer)

            const existingUser = await userService.getAuthExistingUser(userMetadata.email)
            let createdUser: { user_id: string }

            if (!existingUser) {
                console.log('TEST IS PASSING HERE')
                createdUser = await userService.createUser({
                    email: userMetadata.email,
                    wallet_pubaddress: userMetadata.publicAddress,
                    last_login_at: user.claim.iat,
                    issuer: user.issuer,
                })
                console.log('CREATED USER', createdUser)


                done(null, existingUser ? { user_id: existingUser.user_id } : createdUser)
            } else {
                if (user.claim.iat <= existingUser.last_login_at.getTime() / 1000) {
                    this.logger.error(`Replay attack detected for user ${user.issuer}`)
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: `Replay attack detected for user ${user.issuer}}.`,
                    })
                }

                await userService.updateLastLogin(user.issuer, user.claim.iat)

                return done(null, { user_id: existingUser.user_id })
            }
        },
        )
    }
}
```

I am testing the above code with the following test file:

magic.strategy.spec.ts:

```js
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing'
import { Request } from 'express'
import { PrismaService } from '../../prisma.service'
import { UsersService } from '../../users/users.service'
import { MagicStrategy } from './magic.strategy'

describe('MagicStrategy', () => {
    let magicStrategy: MagicStrategy
    let usersService: UsersService
    let configService: ConfigService

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [MagicStrategy, UsersService, ConfigService, PrismaService],
        })
        .overrideProvider(UsersService)
        .useValue({
            getAuthExistingUser: jest.fn(),
            createUser: jest.fn(),
        })
        .overrideProvider(ConfigService)
        .useValue({ get: jest.fn() })
        .compile()

        magicStrategy = module.get<MagicStrategy>(MagicStrategy)
        usersService = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService)
        configService = module.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService)
    })

    describe('validate', () => {
        it('should create a new user if the user does not exist', async () => {
            const user = {
                issuer: 'someissuer',
                claim: {
                    iat: 1234567890,
                },
            }
            const createdUser = { user_id: 'newuserid' }
            const done = jest.fn()
            jest.spyOn(usersService, 'getAuthExistingUser').mockResolvedValue(null)
            jest.spyOn(usersService, 'createUser').mockResolvedValue({ user_id: 'user-id' })

            await magicStrategy.authenticate({ headers: { authorization: 'bearer 1234556' } } as Request)

            expect(configService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('MAGIC_SECRET_KEY')
            expect(usersService.getAuthExistingUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith('email')
            expect(usersService.createUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
                email: 'email',
                wallet_pubaddress: 'publicAddress',
                last_login_at: user.claim.iat,
                issuer: user.issuer,
            })
            expect(done).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null, createdUser)
        })
    })
})
```

However, The test is failing with the following error:

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: {"email": "email", "issuer": "someissuer", "last_login_at": 1234567890, "wallet_pubaddress": "publicAddress"}

Number of calls: 0Jest
```

This is odd because the method `usersService.getAuthExistingUser` is indeed called and passed the assertion. Furthermore, I added some logging inside the mockFunction and can see the logs. I also added logs after the `createUser` statement in the `magic.strategy.ts` file and the log is called.

**Test logs**
I am seeing both console logs from the method in my test logs as shown below:

```
 FAIL  src/auth/passport-strategies/magic.strategy.spec.ts
  ● Console

    console.log
      TEST IS PASSING HERE

      at MagicStrategy.log (auth/passport-strategies/magic.strategy.ts:26:14)

    console.log
      CREATED USER { user_id: 'user-id' }

      at MagicStrategy.log (auth/passport-strategies/magic.strategy.ts:33:14)

  ● MagicStrategy › validate › should create a new user if the user does not exist

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: {"email": "email", "issuer": "someissuer", "last_login_at": 1234567890, "wallet_pubaddress": "publicAddress"}

    Number of calls: 0
```

So logs are showing that the `mockResolvedValue` is indeed working. My next guess would be that the `jest.spyOn(...., createUser)` is not bound to the correct instance?

Answer (score 0):

Your `jest.spyOn(usersService, 'getAuthExistingUser').mockImplementation(null)` should be `jest.spyon(usersService, 'getAuthExistingUser').mockResolvedValue(null)`. Right now, you're essentially calling `const existingUser = await null`, which I assume jest is passing in some other implementation if that's the case. In the end, most likely your `!existingUser` test is returning `false` causing your `createUser` method to never be called.

Comment: I replaced mockImplementation with mockResolvedValue, the logs from withing the `if` condition are outputted, and the `mock` created user is also displayed in the test logs. Meaning the problem may come from the `spyOn` call that is not bound to the correct instance? Weird as both spies are declared exactly the same and one does not work...

Answer (score -1):

If I correctly understand your question, I think the problem here is that the method `usersService.getAuthExistingUser` is not being called properly or with the right parameters. Now this is connected to `getAuthExistingUser` in your mock method service which is not returning the value it is supposed to. I mean it is giving incorrect value.

So here I can think of making the `getAuthExistingUser` return a valid value when we call it with the expected parameters. SO here I would suggest trying out an example which would look something like this to update your test.

We use `mockResolvedValue` for specifying the return values of the mocked methods, so that we can be sure that the test runs as expected.

```js
it('should create a new user if the user does not exist', async () => {
  const user = {
    issuer: 'someissuer',
    claim: {
      iat: 1234567890,
    },
  };
  const createdUser = { user_id: 'newuserid' };
  const done = jest.fn();

  jest.spyOn(usersService, 'getAuthExistingUser').mockResolvedValue(null);

  jest.spyOn(usersService, 'createUser').mockResolvedValue(createdUser);

  await magicStrategy.authenticate({ headers: { authorization: 'bearer 1234556' } } as Request);

  expect(configService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('MAGIC_SECRET_KEY');
  expect(usersService.getAuthExistingUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith('email');
  expect(usersService.createUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    email: 'email',
    wallet_pubaddress: 'publicAddress',
    last_login_at: user.claim.iat,
    issuer: user.issuer,
  });
  expect(done).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null, createdUser);
});
```